# How to call size_t os_proc_available_memory(void) with swift

Tags: swift, objective-c, memory-management

I've never had to call a Obj C function from Swift and most of the info I see out there is for importing frameworks and such so I'm having trouble understanding how to get the data I need.

I want to get the total free memory available to my app and all I can find is https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/3191911-os_proc_available_memory.  I am fine assigning it as a double/int/float/string, whatever.  But I haven't figured out how to call this function to get the value.

So if I open up a playground and write the following:

```
import OSLog
import os

func getMemory() -> Int {
    let size = os_proc_available_memory()
    os_log("\(size)")
}
```

I am getting the error: Cannot find 'os_proc_available_memory' in scope.

This function is basically what I am trying to do as I have been tasked with logging several datapoints including available memory using a logging framework.

Thanks!

Comment: What’s the problem?

Comment: I'll add more to the post.

Comment: Don’t forget the parentheses: `let memoryAvailable = os_proc_available_memory()`

Comment: Quite right, but still no go.  Even with empty () or (void)
        return size_t os_proc_available_memory(void) same error.

Comment: It is available (for iOS 13+, not for macOS) if you include `<os/proc.h>` in the bridging header file.

Comment: My tip: If anything unexpected happens in a Playground, use a compiled project instead. The diagnostic messages and debugging facilities are *much* better.

Comment: I will post a full answer, but it was just that I needed the bridging header file with #include <os/proc.h>.  Thanks Martin!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by Martin R in the comments, it was simply that I needed to add os/proc.h  to the bridging header.

```
#include <os/proc.h>
```

Now I can call the function as written above in my compiled project successfully.

Thanks!